# Undefined index Error Post Php function argument

Tags: php, post

I am very new to php
doing this login form. 
created a file **client.txt** has a text "client"

after when i run the code i get

> "Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mateen\aPanel\userform.php on line 17" ERROR

I could not able to understand where i am doing wrong.

```
<?php

    function isPassword($thePassword){
        $fp = fopen('datafile/client.txt', 'r');
        $code = fgets($fp);
        echo $code;
        fclose($fp);
        if(trim($code)==trim($thePassword)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }



    if(isPassword($_POST['password'])){
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['SESS_CLIENT'] = 1;   
    }else{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['SESS_CLIENT'] = 0;   
    }


    //header("location:../index.php");
?>
```

Comment: `Notice: Undefined index: password` means the `$_POST` array does not have index password

Comment: a field with name password is not submitted along with form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a check `empty` `data` and `index`-

```
if(!empty($_POST['password']) && isPassword($_POST['password'])){....
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make sure that your form field that used to submit password has the attribute name "password"

ie `<input type="password" name="password">`

try it but this time use:

```
if(isset($_POST['password']) && isPassword($_POST['password'])){
```

Comment: `attribute name =  "password"`

Answer (score 1):

Change
`if(isPassword($_POST['password'])){`

to

```
 if(isset($_POST['password']) && isPassword($_POST['password'])){
```

That notice simply tells you that $_POST doesn't have "password" as an index. If you don't submit a form, it's normal.

Answer (score 0):

> "Notice: Undefined index: password in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mateen\aPanel\userform.php on line 17" ERROR

That means, you didn't set `name` attribute to that input type or you might have someother name.

Since you didn't posted your `html` file, i can't exactly tell where you made mistake. But, generally it should be,

```
Password : <input type="password" name="password" />
```

& in `php` file you should check it's empty or not and whether variable `password` is set or not by,

```
if(isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST["password"]))
  {  

   }
```

**NOTE :** Your form method should be `POST`.